# A priori partitioning of a text

Tags: sections-paragraphs

before I write the an article, I would like to roughly partition the text.
The sections and images should be where they are in the final article, with white space where the text is supposed to be.

For that, I would need placeholders that consists of a certain number of white spaces, which automatically reduce as soon as I add real text. (I load the single chapters as single files into the main file and maybe here "filling up the text with white spaces" is possible)

One could hence compare it to a "Latex-form" for the text.

Does a package or a method like this exists?

Comment: This is the complete opposite of everything LaTeX is trying to do.  Could you elaborate on why you want to do that?

Comment: Latex is supposed to fill up a defined space with blank spaces when no real text is provided.  Why is it the opposite? Latex could regard each part as a text and combine those texts.

Comment: It is not very different from \vspace*{\fill} but with being able to set how much space is set or letting it adapt to the remaining space.

Comment: It would be hard (and very weird) to do in tex especially if the filling space had to span a page break, at the level of a single paragraph it's easy enough, `\par\ifnum\prevgraf<10 \vspace*{\dimexpr10\baselineskip-\prevgraf\baselineskip}\fi` will ensure the paragraph just finished has 10 lines including possible final padding space.